# ffplay custom command to seek 5 instead of 10 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, command, keyboard-shortcuts

In ffplay the left/right arrows can be used to skip forward/back 10 seconds. Can I somehow create a custom shortcut (or replace the existing one) to skip only 5 or 3 seconds?

Comment: No. The seek span is hardcoded to 10 seconds.

Comment: If you can edit surce code, not official sample is here(not test).

https://github.com/cho-dev/FFmpeg-jwmod/commit/67a16d32198b047a513f1992e4561844b9a97875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option has now been added to ffplay to allow custom seek interval.

Usage:

```
ffplay file.mp4 -seek_interval 15.6
```

Now the left and right keys will seek to 15.6 seconds (or to the latest keyframe before the seek target) backward and forward.

Comment: was this implemented based on my request here? awesome in any case.

Comment: Yes, it was a small change.